# php setcookie explicitly to localhost

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, cookies, setcookie

I am trying to coordinate cookies that were set by setcookie in PHP with cookie in Rails. The problem is when I set the cookie to localhost domain in PHP with COOKIE_DOMAIN false it sets it to domain 127.0.0.1. However Rails settings to localhost domain instead of 127.0.0.1 domain uses localhost. Therefore I have two different domains (127.0.0.1 and localhost) to localhost domain. How can I fix it, to set the cookie explicitly to localhost domain with setcookie.

Thanks!

Comment: What URL are your PHP and rails applications running on, respectively?

Comment: @Pekka, you was right, it was so simple, it's difference in paths ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie's domain depends on the current domain  when the cookie is set. Make sure both your applications are pointing to `localhost` - then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )`

You need to set `$domain` manually to 'localhost'

Comment: Have you tried this? I don't think it will work. You can't set cookies to belong to other domains like that

Comment: You can set a domain e.g. to '.domain.com' to also match subdomains, so it's just a thought. haven't actally tried it.